# Narrow Union by shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pylance

How to narrow `Union` by shape? I don't want to check actual types with `isinstance` or manual casting (there are a lot of types). Also I can't modify type definitions.

```
class X:
    title = "1"
class Y:
    name = "2"
class Z:
    name = "3"

for (i, r) in enumerate([X(), Y(), Z()]): # type of r: X | Y | Z

    if hasattr(r, "title"):
        print(r.title) # error
    else:
        print(r.name)  # error
```

Type check error says:

```
(variable) title: str | Unknown
Cannot access member "title" for type "Y"
  Member "title" is unknown
Cannot access member "title" for type "Z"
  Member "title" is unknown

(variable) name: Unknown | str
Cannot access member "name" for type "X"
  Member "name" is unknown
```

Comment: Seems like a legit python code to me. Where do you get this error from? Python 3.9.0 handles this code correctly.

Comment: @Sasha There is an error while type checking with Pylance

Comment: Maybe it's a version thing? Pylance v2021.12.1 in VSCode does not give me any error. Or should I enable something there?

Comment: Ah. I see it now. Needed to set `"python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "basic"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue

In a way Pylance checker is correct.

The types are unrelated. There would be no check errors for related types:

```
class Base:
    title: str
    name: str

class X(Base):
    title = "1"
class Y(Base):
    name = "2"
class Z(Base):
    name = "3"

for (i, r) in enumerate([X(), Y(), Z()]): # type of r: X | Y | Z

    if hasattr(r, "title"):
        print(r.title) # no error
    else:
        print(r.name) # no error
```

Also, [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is not applicable here since the set of members is different. There would be no errors if types were considered equivalent:

```
class X:
    name: str
    title = "1"
class Y:
    name = "2"
    title: str
class Z:
    name = "3"
    title: str

for (i, r) in enumerate([X(), Y(), Z()]): # type of r: X | Y | Z

    if hasattr(r, "title"):
        print(r.title) # no error
    else:
        print(r.name) # no error
```

### Workaround

Although you can trick the Pylance checker so it won't complain about the code, there are a couple of options:

##### Option 1. [Suppress](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#compatibility-with-other-uses-of-function-annotations) type checks

```
class X:
    title = "1"
class Y:
    name = "2"
class Z:
    name = "3"

for (i, r) in enumerate([X(), Y(), Z()]): # type of r: X | Y | Z

    if hasattr(r, "title"):
        print(r.title) # type: ignore
    else:
        print(r.name) # type: ignore
```

##### Option 2. Use dynamic access with `getattr` instead of direct member access

```
class X:
    title = "1"
class Y:
    name = "2"
class Z:
    name = "3"

for (i, r) in enumerate([X(), Y(), Z()]): # type of r: X | Y | Z

    if hasattr(r, "title"):
        print(getattr(r, "title"))
    else:
        print(getattr(r, "name"))
```

Comment: I will wait some time before accepting this in the hope of a real solution

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic, Yes, sorry. Updated the answer with more details.

Comment: I was hoping for something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDeAoK6oDsCGBbCAXFAM7ABOAlpgOYoC+KokUAmgsmhjvkaZTfUbhoALXaoMUYBWAAbQiXJVaDAPSqoACwD2ANwhkoAYwCuZYtsPBtJCNCYRiKAGaWoACnnAoADyjbnKABtJDoAGmRwyIBdKGxiYJgwljCRaIBKFAkMCkD3AHJuCHyoKl9MyUkjbUwLeQA6WW1qdx96ovSodV9ShLgAH1ZOdAhZYghhyura7QamlrbpOQhO7r8KBJF6IA

Comment: Btw, in your first and second example `hasattr` check is always true

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic, no, it's not :) `Base` has them declared as instance variables without default. My understanding is that in this case, `Base` will behave as an interface.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I'm not good at python classes

Comment: I kinda hoped I could do it with Python 3.10 and new pattern matching, but it seems there is no way around specifying a type, which effectively would be the same as using `isinstance`.